# Transform html into object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I am trying to convert

```
  myHtml = `
  <span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify;">
  
  In nec <i>convallis</i> justo. Quisque egestas mollis nibh non hendrerit. <strong>Phasellus</strong> tempus sapien in ultricies aliquet. Maecenas nec risus viverra tortor rhoncus venenatis in sit amet enim. Integer id ipsum non leo finibus sagittis in eu velit. Curabitur sed dolor dui. <span>Mauris <strong>aliquam <i>magna</i></strong> a ipsum</span> tincidunt tempor vitae sit amet ante. Maecenas pellentesque augue vitae quam faucibus, vel convallis dolor placerat. Pellentesque semper justo a turpis euismod, ac gravida enim suscipit.</span>
  `;
```

into

```
  data = [
    {
      openTag:
        '<span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify;">',
      closingTag: "</span>",
      children: [
        { value: "In nec" },
        { openTag: "<i>", value: "convallis", closingTag: "</i>" },
        { value: " justo. Quisque egestas mollis nibh non hendrerit. " },
        { openTag: "<strong>", value: "Phasellus", closingTag: "</strong>" },
        {
          value:
            " tempus sapien in ultricies aliquet. Maecenas nec risus viverra tortor rhoncus venenatis in sit amet enim. Integer id ipsum non leo finibus sagittis in eu velit. Curabitur sed dolor dui. "
        },
        {
          opentag: "<span>",
          children: [
            { value: "Mauris " },
            {
              opentag: "<strong>",
              childeren: [
                { value: "aliquam" },
                { opentag: "<i>", value: "magna", closingTag: "</i>" }
              ],
              closingTag: "</strong>"
            },
            { value: " a ipsum" }
          ],
          closingTag: "</span>"
        },
        {
          value:
            " tincidunt tempor vitae sit amet ante. Maecenas pellentesque augue vitae quam faucibus, vel convallis dolor placerat. Pellentesque semper justo a turpis euismod, ac gravida enim suscipit."
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Current Output

```
{
  "rawTagName": null,
  "children": [
    {
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "rawTagName": "span",
      "children": [
        {
          "value": "\n  \n  In nec "
        },
        {
          "rawTagName": "i",
          "value": "convallis"
        },
        {
          "value": " justo. Quisque egestas mollis nibh non hendrerit. "
        },
        {
          "rawTagName": "strong",
          "value": "Phasellus"
        },
        {
          "value": " tempus sapien in ultricies aliquet. Maecenas nec risus viverra tortor rhoncus venenatis in sit amet enim. Integer id ipsum non leo finibus sagittis in eu velit. Curabitur sed dolor dui. "
        },
        {
          "rawTagName": "span",
          "children": [
            {
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "rawTagName": "strong",
              "children": [
                {
                  "value": "aliquam "
                },
                {
                  "rawTagName": "i",
                  "value": "magna"
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "value": " tincidunt tempor vitae sit amet ante. Maecenas pellentesque augue vitae quam faucibus, vel convallis dolor placerat. Pellentesque semper justo a turpis euismod, ac gravida enim suscipit."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is my current approach using recursion

```
import { parse } from "node-html-parser";

// Write Javascript code!

const myHtml = `
  <span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify;">
  
  In nec <i>convallis</i> justo. Quisque egestas mollis nibh non hendrerit. <strong>Phasellus</strong> tempus sapien in ultricies aliquet. Maecenas nec risus viverra tortor rhoncus venenatis in sit amet enim. Integer id ipsum non leo finibus sagittis in eu velit. Curabitur sed dolor dui. <span>Mauris <strong>aliquam <i>magna</i></strong> a ipsum</span> tincidunt tempor vitae sit amet ante. Maecenas pellentesque augue vitae quam faucibus, vel convallis dolor placerat. Pellentesque semper justo a turpis euismod, ac gravida enim suscipit.</span>
  `;

const tranform = str => {
  const nodeAsObject = root => {
    if (root.childNodes.length === 0) {
      return { value: root.rawText };
    }
    if (
      root.childNodes.length === 1 &&
      root.childNodes[0].childNodes.length === 0
    ) {
      return {
        rawTagName: root.rawTagName,
        value: root.rawText
      };
    }
    return {
      rawTagName: root.rawTagName,
      children: root.childNodes.map(x => {
        return {
          rawTagName: x.rawTagName,
          children: x.childNodes.map(y => {
            return nodeAsObject(y);
          })
        };
      })
    };
  };
  return nodeAsObject(parse(str));
};

console.log(tranform(myHtml));

const pre = document.getElementById("pre");
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tranform(myHtml), null, "  ");
```

[Stackblitz Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-uaw5gf?file=index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went for the recursive approach and created an output that is similar to your expected output.

```js
const myHtml = `
  <span style="font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; text-align: justify;">

  In nec <i>convallis</i> justo. Quisque egestas mollis nibh non hendrerit. <strong>Phasellus</strong> tempus sapien in ultricies aliquet. Maecenas nec risus viverra tortor rhoncus venenatis in sit amet enim. Integer id ipsum non leo finibus sagittis in eu velit. Curabitur sed dolor dui. <span>Mauris <strong>aliquam <i>magna</i></strong> a ipsum</span> tincidunt tempor vitae sit amet ante. Maecenas pellentesque augue vitae quam faucibus, vel convallis dolor placerat. Pellentesque semper justo a turpis euismod, ac gravida enim suscipit.</span>
  `;

let revisedHtml;

const parser = htmlStr => {
  let htmlElements = parse(htmlStr);
  revisedHtml = htmlElements.childNodes.map(node => {
    return createTranslatedNode(node);
  });
  return htmlElements;
};

const createTranslatedNode = node => {
  let currentNode = {};
  // This is a textNode.
  if (!node.rawTagName) {
    currentNode = { value: node?.rawText?.trim() };
  }
  // This is a tagNode
  if (node.rawTagName) {
    currentNode = {
      openTag: `<${node.rawTagName} ${node.rawAttrs}>`,
      closingTag: `</${node.rawTagName}>`
    };
  }

  if (node?.childNodes?.length === 1 && !node?.childNodes[0].rawTagName) {
    currentNode.value = node?.childNodes[0].rawText?.trim();
  }

  if (node?.childNodes?.length > 1) {
    currentNode.children = node.childNodes.map(childNode => {
      return createTranslatedNode(childNode);
    });
  }

  return currentNode;
};

console.log(revisedHtml);
```

I do some assumptions with the open and close tags since I just do some string concatination to add the `<>` around the tags.
Other than that I `trim()` the value inputs to remove the unwanted whitespace around the value.

This does make some assumptions about the html, like it always having start and closing tags, and such. A further improvement that could be done would be to test for that also.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this out